# How Apple TV is used to control Homekit Accesory

Tags: ios, swift, apple-tv, homekit

I have created an application for `Homekit` which works fine when both accessory and device is in same network.

I read somewhere that `Apple TV` is required to control accessories remotely.

Can anybody please tell how to achieve this exactly?

Comment: Apple has confirmed that AppleTV will be used to control HomeKit remotely. See this support page for details. https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204893

Answer (score 0):

If you have Apple TV try to set it up. 
I have given the details.

I have done a much workaround for this. First of all handling things by our own is not preferable for multiple users.

I had this query that how all configuration done on one device will reflect on another device for same home. Unfortunately apple didn't provided much information on this and they also didn't clarify that Apple TV will require or not(As I have referred to some reports that says Apple TV will use as intermediator between iOS devices.

Now at application side i have tried to add User to home. There is a HMUser class and we can add user to any home that we want to sync. I was running my app in iOS 8.1 in both the devices, I was also logged in to icloud and keychain access was also enabled.

Now i have tried to add user using method of HMHome class

-addUserWithCompletionHandler()

I shows a popup in which we need to enter the email id of user to which we want to give access to current home.

But it didn't work. I always get error "notification not enable at remote side"

I think that login to Apple TV is require for adding user. I am not sure about this, Apple hasn't clarify on this too. I don't have Apple TV if you have try to login in it and use two other iOS devices to give access to any icloud account.

Also revert me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not pair homekit with the appleTV. You can use the [remote app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/remote/id284417350?mt=8) either from you iPhone or iPad

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on HAP Over iCloud concept since last 2 to 3 hours. The beauty in this concept is according to the documentation we should need the following things.

```
1. Apple tv 3rd generation.

2. Have to use same iCloud account in both apple tv and iOS device.

3. This is most important that Apple tv and Accessory should be on same network.
```

Eventhough you are on different network it is able to pass the switch on/off,brightness increase/decrease ... actions. For this you can use siri commands or programmatically call the accessory write value functionality

Note : As I know I think when you are passing the commands to the Accessory it checks for the iCloud account in the apple tv and from there it is passing the commands to the Accessory.